# Inserting a loop into a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

How do I get my output to look like this with the Week number inserted?

```
Week 1
Monday, January 18, 2016
Wednesday, January 20, 2016
Friday, January 22, 2016
Week 2
Monday, January 25, 2016
Wednesday, January 27, 2016
Friday, January 29, 2016
Week 3
Monday, February 01, 2016
Wednesday, February 03, 2016
Friday, February 05, 2016
```

Here is my code:

```
$d = new DateTime('2016-01-17');
$inc = new DateInterval('P1D');
$dateOptions = '';
$required = array(1,3,5);
for ($i=0; $i<28; ++$i) {
$d = $d->add($inc);
if (in_array($d->format('w'), $required)) {
     $t = $d->format('l, F d, Y');
         echo "$t<br \>";   
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = new DateTime('2016-01-17');
$inc = new DateInterval('P1D');
$dateOptions = '';
$required = array(1,3,5);
$j = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i <28; ++$i) {
    $d = $d->add($inc);
    if($d->format('w') == 1){
        echo 'Week '.$j.PHP_EOL;
        $j++;
    }
    if (in_array($d->format('w'), $required)) {
        $t = $d->format('l, F d, Y');
        echo $t.PHP_EOL;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$d = new DateTime('2016-01-17');
$inc = new DateInterval('P1D');
$dateOptions = '';
$required = array(1,3,5);
$counter = $week = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<28; ++$i){
    $d = $d->add($inc);
    if (in_array($d->format('w'), $required)) {
        if($counter % 3 == 0){
            echo "Week " . ($week + 1) . "<br />";
            ++$week;
        }
        $t = $d->format('l, F d, Y');
        echo $t . "<br />";   
        ++$counter;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Week 1
Monday, January 18, 2016
Wednesday, January 20, 2016
Friday, January 22, 2016
Week 2
Monday, January 25, 2016
Wednesday, January 27, 2016
Friday, January 29, 2016
Week 3
Monday, February 01, 2016
Wednesday, February 03, 2016
Friday, February 05, 2016
Week 4
Monday, February 08, 2016
Wednesday, February 10, 2016
Friday, February 12, 2016
```

`$counter` will keep track of number of dates being printed and `$week` will print the week number after every three dates.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.

I'm getting output like this:

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.

When using this code:
'$d = new DateTime('2016-07-14');
$required = array(1,2,3,4);'

I'm getting output like this:
Week 1
Monday, July 18, 2016
Tuesday, July 19, 2016
Wednesday, July 20, 2016
Thursday, July 21, 2016
Week 2
Monday, July 25, 2016
Tuesday, July 26, 2016
ect...

Instead of this:
Week 1
Thursday, July 14, 2016
Week 2
Monday, July 18, 2016
Tuesday, July 19, 2016
etc...

How would I change it?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want...

```
$d = new DateTime('2016-01-17');
$inc = new DateInterval('P1D');
$dateOptions = '';
$required = array(1,3,5);
$week = null;
$week_no = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<28; ++$i) {
$d = $d->add($inc);
if (in_array($d->format('w'), $required)) {
  if($week!=$d->format('W')){
    $week_no++;
    $week = $d->format('W');
    echo "Week $week_no<br \>";
  }

   $t = $d->format('l, F d, Y');
       echo "$t<br \>";   
  }
}
```

The `$week` variable keeps track of the dates Week number (from the PHP `date()` function).

The `$week_no` keeps track of your incremental number of weeks starting at 1.

The if statement check to see if the the current week number is different to the previous weeks (`$week`). If it's different it adds 1 to your `$week_no` a is different to the previous

Answer (score 0):

check http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> W => ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP 4.1.0)

you just need to add this if before the date printing

```
if ($d->format('w') == 1){
  echo "Week " . $d->format('W') . "<br \>";
}
```

something like this will do the trick

```
  $d = new DateTime('2016-01-17');
  $inc = new DateInterval('P1D');
  $dateOptions = '';
  $required = array(1,3,5);
  for ($i=0; $i<28; ++$i) {
    $d = $d->add($inc);

    if ($d->format('w') == 1){
      echo "Week " . $d->format('W') . "<br \>";
    }
    if (in_array($d->format('w'), $required)) {
     $t = $d->format('l, F d, Y');
     echo "$t<br \>";
    }
  }
```

*Output:*

```
Week 01
Monday, January 18, 2016
Wednesday, January 20, 2016
Friday, January 22, 2016
Week 02
Monday, January 25, 2016
Wednesday, January 27, 2016
Friday, January 29, 2016
Week 03
Monday, February 01, 2016
Wednesday, February 03, 2016
Friday, February 05, 2016
Week 04
Monday, February 08, 2016
Wednesday, February 10, 2016
Friday, February 12, 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
$d = new DateTime('2016-01-17');
$inc = new DateInterval('P1D');
$dateOptions = '';
$required = array(1,3,5);
$counter = $week = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<21; ++$i){
$d = $d->add($inc);
if (in_array($d->format('w'), $required)) {
    if($counter % 3 == 0){
        $week_num = $week + 1;
            echo "Week $week_num<br />";
        ++$week;
    }
    $t = $d->format('l, F d, Y');
        echo  "$t<br />";   
    ++$counter;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Week 1
Monday, January 18, 2016
Wednesday, January 20, 2016
Friday, January 22, 2016
Week 2
Monday, January 25, 2016
Wednesday, January 27, 2016
Friday, January 29, 2016
Week 3
Monday, February 01, 2016
Wednesday, February 03, 2016
Friday, February 05, 2016
```